# Can you make Mac's Menu Bar hide?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

We all know you can simply click "turn hiding on" in Dock's Preferences, but can you do the same thing to Mac's **Menu Bar**?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As of OS X El Capitan (10.11), this functionality is built in to the operating system. Go to System Preferences > General  and turn on "Automatically hide and show the menu bar."

[image]

Here is how it works:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From my dear friend Google :

You can't hide menu bar without using other apps. See > http://osxdaily.com/2011/02/24/hide-mac-menu-bar/ Note that when you are using a full-screen application, menu bar is hidden and it appears when you move the cursor to the top of your screen

Comment: That's kind of the problem. I want to make it stop popping up when I'm watching a video on fullscreen.

Comment: @cedeelbe you should add more info about your issue if its the same as the OP one, or post another question